# Not able to create jdbc-sink connector: ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector'

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create jdbc sink connector on kafka-connect(not on confluent), and I am struggling with the following error:

```
ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector'
```

I have set below path in CLASSPATH, and placed all jdbc connect related JARs.
C:\Oviyan\Software\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\libs
C:\Oviyan\Software\confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.1\lib

> **Config properties:**

**connect-standalone.properties:**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=C:<user-name>\Software\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\libs\kafka-connect-jdbc
rest.port=8086
rest.host.name=localhost
```

**Jdbc-connect-config.properties:**

```
  name=test-sink-jdbc-autoincrement
  connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  tasks.max=1
  topics=test-topic
  connection.url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/<db-name>
  connection.user=
  connection.password=
  auto.create=true
```

Error Log:

```
   ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' was not found. 
   Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@3a1dd365 

    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found 
   for jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/kafka-test1


   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/kafka- 
   test1
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It would seem you have not put `C:\Oviyan\Software\confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.1\lib` into your `plugin.path`

Comment: Please refer https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#no-suitable-driver-found

Comment: Thanks for responding. i have tried that too and created folder "kafka-connect-jdbc" under lib and tried. but no luck

Comment: Is the Postgres JDBC driver in that folder? Is there a reason not to just use Confluent Platform's already downloaded JDBC connector as compared to setting it up from just Apache Kafka's download folder? Also, I would recommend not putting anything into Kafka lib folder, and rather isloate your connectors somewhere else on disk

Comment: Thanks cricket_007!. our requirement is simple and its just for POC. by the way, i followed your suggestion, still im getting same issue.

Comment: Again, is the postgres JAR folder there? Did you go through that whole blog on the debugging sections? Do you see the driver loaded in the logs?

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, it worked!

Comment: hi, how can you solve your problem